# A bash script to check the tar.gz files

Tags: bash, centos

I have the following script that I would like to run after a cPanel backup is created (1 .tar.gz file per websites) to check the compressed files. Its not meant to replace manual test restores, but just an extra check. The problem is instead of resturning a list of files that failed the check it returns a list of all the files.

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
path="/backups/$date/*.gz"

found_errors=0
errors='The following backup files failed the automatic test: \n'

for f in $path
do
        gunzip -c $f | tar t > /dev/null

        #if the exit status was not 0
        if [ $?=0 ]; then
                found_errors=1
                errors="$errors\n$f"
                #echo  $f ": Exit status code is " $?
        fi
done

#if an error was found
if [ $found_erros!=0 ]; then
        #email the list of files that could not be extracted/tested
        echo -e $errors | mail -s "Backup Error Check" "admin@example.com"
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a typo. I bet the check on the status should be

```
#if the exit status was not 0
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```